# install_github("riv","tomasgreif") Error in parse_repo_spec(repo) : Invalid git repo specification: 'riv'

Tags: r

While trying to:

```
install_github("riv","tomasgreif")
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in parse_repo_spec(repo) : Invalid git repo specification: 'riv'

Comment: `install_github(repo_owner/reponame)` and `riv` doesn't exist. What's the link to the repo? A `riv` search: https://github.com/search?l=R&q=riv&type=Repositories

Comment: There is riv on CRAN, maybe try: `install.packages("riv")` ?

Comment: https://github.com/cran/riv.git

Comment: Just to summarize. My end target is to get the Information value and Weight of evidence for all the independent variables and gather Variable selection using Information Value. Is there any other library

Comment: It would be better to ask a new question with sample data, current and expected output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5):

Use of `install_github("riv","tomasgreif")`seems to be deprecated. Try using following format

```
install_github('repo owner/repo name')
```

in your case

```
install_github('tomasgreif/riv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Package `riv` was [renamed](https://github.com/tomasgreif/woe/commit/87210fb67dddc382e40de2d87bb53c54882c1ebc) to `woe`. The author [states](https://github.com/tomasgreif/woe):

> THIS PACKAGE IN NOT MAINTAINED ANYMORE. I KEEP IT HERE ONLY BECAUSE SOME PEOPLE FIND IT INTERESTING

Installing from GitHub like so: `devtools::install_github("tomasgreif/riv")` installs `woe`. That said, there is an R package called `riv` on CRAN.